# How to format number in XSLT to add a thousand seperator in between

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to add a thousand seperator but can't seem to work the numbers appeared all the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:decimal-format name="pop" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator=","/>


    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(26813057, '##,###,###','pop')" />
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<pop>
  <population>26813057</population>
  <population>19357594</population>
</pop>
```

What I got was all 26,813,057, when i want to pull individual datas from the XML content.

Comment: What is your XSLT processor?

Comment: Check it out here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44066832/xslt-how-to-use-format-number-and-decimal-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="pop">
        <xsl:for-each select="population">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '##,##,###')"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

**DEMO:** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHc